# Problema con async/await

Tags: javascript, async-await

Trabajé muchas veces con `async/await` pero en este caso no encuentro la forma de tener el comportamiento deseado. ¿Cómo puedo llamar a la función `GoogleState` y que continúe el flujo (lo que sería el primer `console.log`) **sólo** cuando la función haya terminado?. Sé que funciona porque el `console.log` del `setTimeout` sí da el resultado esperado. Aqui el código:

```
let state;

async function GoogleState() {
    gapi.load('auth2', async function () {
        await gapi.auth2.init({ client_id: 'xxxxxxx' });

        await gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().then(instance => {
            GoogleAuth = instance
            state = GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.get();
        });
    });
}

GoogleState();
console.log(state);
    
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(state);
}, 500);
```

He intentado varias cosas como poner la función `GoogleState` dentro de otra con `async/await` pero tampoco resulta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que `GoogleState` solamente va a ejecutar `gapi.load` y ya, se va a salir y no va a esperar a que termine el callback de `gapi.load`.

La forma de arreglarlo es que `GoogleState` retorne una promesa que se resuelva en cuanto termine todo el callback de `gapi.load`. De la siguiente forma:

```js
// solo para el ejemplo
const gapi = {
  load: (m, cb) => {
    cb();
  },
  auth2: {
    init: (obj) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("Iniciando...", obj);
        setTimeout(resolve, 500);
      }),
    getAuthInstance: () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("Obteniendo la instancia...");
        setTimeout(() => resolve({
          isSignedIn: {
            get: () => ({estado: "Super estado bien padre "})
          }
        }), 600);
      })
  }
};

let state;

/*async <- este async no sirve de nada*/ function GoogleState() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    gapi.load('auth2', async function () {
      // y el try-catch? qué pasa si ocurre un error?
      await gapi.auth2.init({ client_id: 'xxxxxxx' });

      const instance = await gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();  
      GoogleAuth = instance;
      state = GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.get();
      return resolve(state);
    });
  });
}

(async () => {
  await GoogleState();
  console.log("Me ejecuto después de GoogleState. Estado:", state);
})();
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias @Benjamín Guzmán. Aunque la funcion autoejecutable la reemplace por GoogleState().then(state => console.log(state); el cual funciona, aunque no se si sera lo indicado

Answer (score -2):

No funciona porque estas cambiando el valor de state dentro de un contexto diferente al de la variable en tu primera linea.

https://playcode.io/850654/

Es la forma en la que JS funciona y hasta donde sé, no hay forma de sincronizar ambos contextos, para una explicación más técnica te dejo este blog.

http://blog.mediumequalsmessage.com/promise-deferred-objects-in-javascript-pt1-theory-and-semantics

Comment: Y cómo responde esto a la pregunta? Como comentario no está mal, pero no proporciona respuesta a la pregunta, solo le indica lo que está mal. Y si vas a poner un snippet de código, te recomiendo ponerlo utilizando los snippets de SO, especialmente para html/css/js, que permiten ejecutarlo directamente sin abandonar SO.

Comment: @Benito-B ?????

Comment: Las preguntas, expresadas mediante palabras, suelen tener más sentido y significado que solo utilizando símbolos, vamos que no sé qué quieres con los "?????". Y las respuestas expresadas con soluciones son mejores que las que solo indican *qué* está mal, pero no **cómo arreglarlo**. Por cierto para "sincronizar contextos" puedes utilizar el método [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: Creo que el problema que expresa el compañero Hernán es un problema de manejo de asincronidad más que de contexto, porque el que se cambie de valor a `state` en un diferente contexto al que se declaró no debería de afectar en nada, a menos de que esté fuera de scope u otros factores, pero me parece que este no es el caso.